# Change selected index using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi need to change the selected index of a  when another  has been changed..
Example:
i have

```
<select id="selector">
<option>No 1</option>
<option>No 2</option>
</select>
<select id="selected">
<option>ONE</option>
<option>TWO</option>
</select>
```

now i want the $selected index to change when the  #selector's index is changed.. like when i change to "No 2" the other combobox will change to "TWO". pardon me for newbie question but im new to jquery ^^

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
$('#selector').change(function() {
    var idx = this.selectedIndex;        
    $("select#selected").prop('selectedIndex', idx);  
});
```

Comment: thx.. it worked :) i know it's just that simple but my knowledge isnt that great xD

Comment: For all that need to know (because I did): `idx` here holds the value `0` or `1`. The `<option>`s are treated as array indices for `selectedIndex`

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#selector').change(
    function(){
        var index = this.selectedIndex;
        $('#selected option').eq(index).prop('selected',true);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BeTmf/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 3):

Just using regular JavaScript because jQuery seems unnecessary for this:

```
document.getElementById('selector').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('selected').selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
}
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nJ55a/1/)

Answer (score 3):

with **jQuery 1.7.2**

```
$(document).on('change', '#selector', function (){
   var si =  this.selectedIndex
    $('#selected option').eq(si).prop('selected',true);
});​
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zKsKV/)

Answer (score 0):

The selectedIndex starts at 0.

If the drop-down list allows multiple selections it will only return the index of the first option selected.
The value "-1" will deselect all options (if any).
If no option is selected, the selectedIndex property will return -1.

```
$('#idselect').change(function() {
    var index = this.selectedIndex;
    //...
});
```