# Change Textbox from Dropdown List through AJAX, PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a table which consists of 2 columns, ContactName and Usertype. I have a dropdown list which consists of data from ContactName. When I select any value in the dropdown, its Usertype should be shown according to what was selected. Please help me. I have done this much so far. When I select any value in the dropdown, the same value is shown but I want the user type.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start(); 
    }

    $dingo=$_SESSION['dingo'];
    $query11="Select ISO3,Notify,Dingoid from rahul_tbl_users where Dingoid=$dingo";
    $query123=mysql_query($query11);
    $query1234=mysql_fetch_array($query123);
    $fetch=mysql_query("SELECT tdd.Dingoid,tc.Dingoid,tc.A_End,tbidd.OpportunityNumber,        tbidd.Status,tbidd.Country,tbidd.OpportunityName,tbidd.Allocatedto,tbidd.Email,tbidd.Customer,tbidd.Country,tbidd.ContactName,tc.Usertype,tbidd.G1_OPPID
        FROM  scott123.rahul_tbl_users tdd inner join scott123.rahul_user_opps tc on
        tdd.Dingoid=tc.Dingoid Inner Join scott123.rahul_tbl_opportunities tbidd
        on tc.A_End=tbidd.OpportunityNumber
        WHERE tc.Dingoid =$dingo");
    $fetch_result=mysql_fetch_array($fetch);
?>

<form method="post" action="">

<?php
    $SQLString="SELECT distinct(G1_OPPID),ContactName from rahul_tbl_opportunities where G1_OPPID IS NOT NULL and ContactName!='' ";
    $result1 = mysql_query($SQLString); 
    $select_box='<select name="select1"  id="select1" onchange="javascript:load_value(this.value);">';
    $input="";

    while($rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {  
        $select_box .='<option id="user_name" value="'.$rows1["ContactName"].'">'.$rows1['ContactName'].'</option>';  
    }

    $input ='<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="" />';

    echo $select_box."</select>";
    echo $input;
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit_name11" value="Add Permission"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit_name12" value="Edit Permission"/>   
</form>
```

Comment: DO you have something against my eyes?

Comment: where is the javascript you have tried?

Comment: @karthikr The only JavaScript he wrote is the tag

Comment: You would have to include some javascript/jquery like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309817/change-selected-index-using-jquery to achieve what you are looking for. Change the ids to the Ids you use in your implementation

Comment: I am sorry here is my javascript code                          <script type="text/javascript">
      function load_value(value)
     {
         document.getElementById("test").value=value;
     }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

What I gather is you just want the textbox to display what is currently selected in the select box?

Change your onchange event in the select box to be:

```
onchange="transferValue();"
```

And add this script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function transferValue(){
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("select1");
        var selectedOption = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
        var textBox = document.getElementById("test");
        textBox.value = selectedOption;
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        transferValue();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: No actually my textbox value is different than select box.