# How to change index of an item in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, jquery, user-interface, html.dropdownlistfor

Currently I am working on MVC3 website development. There I am facing a problem. I am having a dropdownlist which populates all the countries from database. I need to set index = 0 for a particular country.

How can I achieve it through jquery.

I tried using the below mentioned code, but it didn't worked.

```
$("#ddlCountry").find('[value=Eng]').remove();
$("#ddlCountry").eq(0).before($("<option></option>").val("Eng").text("England"));
```

Comment: Post your code thus far better chance of getting helped that way!

Comment: To avoid performance problems & code bloat, i suggest you order the countries accordingly server-side. sure you can do it with jQuery, it's just not pretty or as efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did for achieving the desired result

```
$("#ddlCountry").find('[value=Eng]').remove();
$("#ddlCountry option").eq(1).before($("<option></option>").val("Eng").text("England"));
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use [prop:](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
 $("#selector").prop('selectedIndex', index);
```

[**HELP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309817/change-selected-index-using-jquery)